# uipickerview selection on tableviewcell detailtextlabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

As I wrote in the title, I am trying to write down the value selected on a pickerview (populated by an array) to the `detailTextLabel` of the cell I clicked to bring up the pickerview. (The pickerview is shown in an actionSheet).

What I tried to do was to set up two mutable arrays: `pickerData` and `tableData`. Initially, the `pickerData`array contains the values shown in the pickerview, and the `tableData` array has only one value.

When the following method is called, I'm trying to record the selection onto the `tableData` array, and then use this value to replace the original value on the `detailTextLabel`

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [tableData replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:[pickerData objectAtIndex:row]];
}
```

The `detailTextLabel` is populated by the `tableData` array, and this happens in the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

using the line of code:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [pickerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

What am I doing wrong? any suggestions on how should I do this differently? I have been programming for only a month and I'm sure this has a simple solution. Thank You in advance!

Comment: what this method do :
 [tableData replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:[pickerData objectAtIndex:row]];

Comment: @MohammadAl-Barari well, what I think it does is replaces the tableData value with the one selected in the picker view.

Comment: you did not checked ma answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOU NEED TO initialize the tableData NSMutableArray :
self.tableData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

```
 id)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
UITableViewCell *cell =[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    [self.tableData insertObject:[pickerData objectAtIndex:row] atIndex:index]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using tableData for updating detailTextLabel but when you have a look at your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 you are using pickerData `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [pickerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` Which is causing problem. You should use `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` and hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I did not realize I copied it like that, when I do use "tableData" the app crashes. So I left it as "pickerData" while I figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your detailTextLabel in your `pickerView didSelectRow` and then set your picker value to this `label`

```
UILabel *detailTextLabel=(UILabel*)[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] detailTextLabel ];

detailTextLabel.text=[pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: could you guide me a little bit more please? where does this fit?